# How can i make drop-down list using multiple attribute in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying use multiple attributes where I make the dropdown list, however it is working but default browser changing. Is there any way I can make it drop-down. Please see the code..

```
    <select name="cars" multiple>
       <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
       <option value="saab">Saab</option>
       <option value="opel">Opel</option>
       <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
```

But if I remove multiple attribute, I can see only drop-down list. Why is it showing different HTML control when I use multiple. I circled correct control with blue that's how I want to use multiple. Is there any suggestion or any ideas.

[image]

Comment: This is the way it displays when you use multiple. This is the way it's supposed to work. How else would you select multiple items? If it drops down and you select one, then the whole list collapses and you only see that one item. It's working fine, but your interpretation of what it is supposed to do is wrong.

Comment: You can use JavaScript with HTML/CSS to create something that behaves like a drop-down list but allows multiple selections (not hiding the list until you click outside the control, or click the arrow button again), but as has already been pointed out it doesn't really make sense to do so given that when the list is not displayed you couldn't see all of the items that were selected.

Answer (score 1):

This code uses the selector's size = "6" attribute,
css code the selector limits the display to one line of the options tag
DOM action hovering over a selector shows the entire selector: hover is the option size = "6", the mouse points to selects one or more selections. The selector parent is the form's frame,
it is needed for relative positioning, children are positioned absolutely by default. This allows you to get a minimalist place for presenting data. The label opens the selector also, the browser handles the DOM after the id attribute and the for attribute are combined in the DOM. With index opens to the top of the next DOM element, if you need to open from the bottom edge of the parent frame, uncomment bottom 0% of the parent's height at the top of the frame.

You can extend this by adding the selected attribute to the first option with the value None, then the server will receive a message that no option has been selected,

you can add the required or patterns attribute for validation if you enter imput as an add option to save data for later selection, this allows you to get information from the user what data he wants to sort but not filter it.

CSS:

```
fieldset {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}

select {
    position: absolute;
    height: 18px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

select:hover {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    /* bottom: 10px; */
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="./shopping.php" method="GET">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Clothes selection</legend>
        <label for="clothes">Select Ctrl+LMB:</label>
        <select multiple id="clothes" name="Outfit" size="6">
                <option value="Trousers" >Trousers</option>
                <option value="Hoodie">Hoodie</option>
                <option value="T-shirt">T-shirt</option>
                <option value="Trousers">Trousers</option>
                <option value="Hoodie">Hoodie</option>
                <option value="T-shirt">T-shirt</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Comment: Thank you for help FluffyKitten, that's a very nice comment from you.

Answer (score 0):

You Can go to web  [http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar]

Copy code and it have Css and HTML

or u can go see in Youtube how to use Bootstrap

Comment: I am not using navbar, i am using dropdown list.

Comment: Yes, u can see right menu list in website http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns or u can go see "CSS" in web https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

Comment: Mr.Anouluck I using multiple select, bootstrap doesn't shows that

Comment: you should download file bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download and Import file CSS All bootstrap, Js.  can see >>> How To use Bootstrap = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GU6EWzBGo64. you can go copy code dropdown Or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okGRZB_0SfI.  BootStrap use very easy for website design

Answer (score 0):

try Bootstrap Multiselect JS library :

http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/